# Convergence Properties of Fourier coefficients

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Note that Let $a_n=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(t)\cos (nt)dt$, where $f\in {C}^1[-\pi,\pi]$ and $f(-\pi)=f(\pi)$. Then,

1) does the sequence $na_n$ converge to $0$ as $n\to\infty$?

2)does the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^2|a_n|^2$ converge?

I think yes to both, because of the boundedness of $na_n$. But, how do we prove the convergence? Thanks beforehend.

Comment: $C^1(-\pi,\pi)$ is not the same as $C^1$ and $2\pi$ periodic. And  integration by parts provides the solution (equivalently, you can look at $h(t) = f(t)+g(t)$ where $g(t)$ is a quadratic polynomial on $[-\pi,\pi]$ and $h(t)$ is $C^1$ and $2\pi$ periodic)

Comment: @user1952009 what do you mean by "$C^1(-\pi,\pi) $ is not same as being $C^1$ and $ 2\pi$ periodic" and what is $h(t)$?

Comment: What do you get when integrating by parts $\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(t) e^{-int}dt$ assuming $f(t)$ is $C^1$ and $2\pi$ periodic ?

Comment: @user1952009 we get $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{-e^{-int}}{in}f'(t)dt$

Comment: Can you answer to the question from this ? Then, what do you get when $f$ is only $C^1$ on $(-\pi,\pi)$, for example $f(t) = t, f(t+2\pi) = f(t)$  ?

Comment: @user1952009 ok, part 1) is solved, but what about part 2)?

Comment: @vidyarthi Part 2) is true, because $f'\in L^2$ and then $(n\hat{f}(n))\in\ell^2$.

Comment: @AD. Are you speaking of Fourier inversion theorem, by any chance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the question for part 2) is easy from [Parseval's Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_identity) applied to $f'$ as pointed out by AD. The first part follows by integration by parts and the boundedness of $f$, as pointed out in the comments. Note that the second part has a more general version for $f$ possessing only weak derivatives.